# Обработка большого файла csv на php. Перезаписать значения колонки

Tags: php, csv

Пытаюсь решить задачу по обработке большого `csv` файла (12194 строки) с товарами, читаю файл с помощью библиотеки [parseCSV](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php)

В файле есть колонка "код модели", мне нужно пройтись по каждой строке и добавить рандомный префикс к коду модели, например:
`MODELCODE_PREF987`
Для этого пишу такой код, используя  методы библиотеки :

```
  <?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    require_once('parsecsv.lib.php');

    $fileCSV = 'file_pred.csv';

    $csv = new parseCSV();
    $csv->delimiter = "\t";
    $csv->parse($fileCSV);

    $count = count($csv->data);

    for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){
            $ID = $csv->data[$i]['Код модели'] . "_" . rand(0,1000);    
            $csv->data[$i]['Код модели'] = $ID;
            $csv->save(); 
    }
```

Но скрипт зависает именно на модификации данных, если сделать просто вывод то все быстро отрабатывает. И скорее всего так и должно быть, в `php` только начинаю разбираться и поэтому мой код скорее всего не правильный. Прошу привести пример
(дополнение к комментарию) метод записи файла

```
 protected function _wfile($file, $string = '', $mode = 'wb', $lock = 2) {
        if ($fp = fopen($file, $mode)) {
            flock($fp, $lock);
            $re = fwrite($fp, $string);
            $re2 = fclose($fp);

            if ($re != false && $re2 != false) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вынести `$csv->save()` из цикла `for()`:

```
//...
for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $ID = $csv->data[$i]['Код модели'] . "_" . rand(0,1000);    
    $csv->data[$i]['Код модели'] = $ID;
} 
$csv->save();
```

У вас получается, что после каждого изменения идет пересохранение файла, а достаточно сохранить файл один раз, в конце, после того как все изменения будут учтены. С этой библиотекой не работал, но посмотрел код библиотеки на гитхабе и думаю, что должно помочь.

Comment: Благодарю вас! Все заработало.

Comment: Заметил следующие, к примеру если файл весит 6 мб то после перезаписи он всегда становиться меньше и весит 4 мб. Даже если файл всего 1 мб то после перезаписи он становиться меньше. В чем может быть трабла?  из зи используемой библиотеке ?

Comment: данные при этом не теряются? я повторюсь, что с этой библиотекой не работал

Comment: теряются, кол-во строк становиться меньше, запись производит вот этот метод:

(дополню в ответ метод записи)

 может ли быть причина в fwrite ? пытался передать третий параметр этой функции filezesize($file) но нечего не меняться

Comment: на localhost все нормально работает, на боевом сервере нет, нужно значит какие - то настройки поменять ?

Comment: похоже на то, что проблема в окружении, но по поводу каких-то конкретных настроек пока ничего не могу сказать. Попробуйте сравнить php.ini локальный с боевым. Какие строки теряются? В конце файла или в середине? Может у вас, к примеру, nginx рубит соединение до того как файл полностью записался